# does Apache Kylin need a Apache Derby or Mysql for run the sample cube

Tags: hadoop, kylin

I installed Java and Hadoop and Hbase and Hive and Spark and Kylin.
hadoop-3.0.3
hbase-1.2.6
apache-hive-2.3.3-bin
spark-2.2.2-bin-without-hadoop
apache-kylin-2.3.1-bin

I will be grateful if someone in Help me with Kyle's installation and configuration them.

Answer (score 1):

http://kylin.apache.org/docs/ this may help you. You can send email to dev@kylin.apache.org, then the questions will be discussed and answered in the mailing list. There are some tips for sending the email: 1. provide Kylin version 2. provide log information 3.provide the usage scenario. If you want to get a quick start, you can run Kylin in a Hadoop sandbox VM or in the cloud, for example, start a small AWS EMR or Azure HDInsight cluster and then install Kylin in one of the nodes. When you use Kylin-2.3.1, I suggest you use Spark-2.1.2.